# Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter

Tags: apex

I develop an Apex class and I am facing to an issue when I save.

> Error: Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter

I can't add a sentence in a map as a value but I can add that same value as a string.

If I write:

```
map<String, String> myMap = new map<String, String>{
...
'17' => 'Equipement de la maison, électroménager',
...
};
```

It doesn't work but if I write:

```
map<String, String> myMap = new map<String, String>{
...
'17' => 'Equipement de la maison, electroménager',
...
};
```

It works.

Also, if I write:

```
String text = 'Equipement de la maison, électroménager';
```

It works.

I understand Salesforce doesn't like special characters but why not all special characters?

This is all my code (error in line 43 for me):
public without sharing class ABT_MapNominationFieldsWithContact{

```
public static map<String, String> accountSecteurActiviteMap = new map<String, String>{
    '1' => 'Administration publique nationale',
    '2' => 'Administration territoriale',
    '3' => 'Développement local',
    '4' => 'Institutions internationales',
    '5' => 'Groupes bancaires',
    '6' => 'Assurance, Réassurance, caisses de retraite',
    '7' => 'Banques de détail',
    '8' => 'Banques de financement et d\'investissement',
    '9' => 'Banques nationales, autorités de tutelle, institutions financières, etc.',
    '10' => 'Banques privées, gestion de fortune',
    '11' => 'Capital Investissement, Business Angels, sociétés de participation',
    '12' => 'Financements spécialisés (leasing, crédit a la consommation)',
    '13' => 'Gestion d\'actifs, services aux investisseurs, sociétés de bourse',
    '14' => 'Autres sociétés financières',
    '15' => 'Biens de consommation alimentaires',
    '16' => 'Droguerie, parfumerie, hygiène, cosmétiques',
    '17' => 'Equipement de la maison, électroménager',
    '18' => 'Equipement de la personne (vêtements, accessoires)',
    '20' => 'Autres biens de consommation non alimentaires',
    '48' => 'Luxe',
    '21' => 'BTP, construction',
    '22' => 'Immobilier, promotion immobilière',
    '75' => 'Logement social',
    '23' => 'Conseil en audit, expertise comptable',
    '24' => 'Conseil en management, stratégie',
    '25' => 'Conseil en relations publiques, communication, marketing',
    '26' => 'Conseil juridique, cabinets d'avocats',
    '27' => 'Conseil RH, recrutement, outplacement',
    '28' => 'Ingénierie, certifications et inspections techniques',
    '29' => 'Autres prestations de conseil',
    '30' => 'Chaînes de restauration',
    '31' => 'Distribution BtoB, négoce',
    '32' => 'Distribution spécialisée',
    '33' => 'E-Commerce, VAD',
    '34' => 'Grande distribution alimentaire',
    '35' => 'Autres sociétés de distribution',
    '79' => 'Logiciels et services informatiques',
    '39' => 'Télécommunications',
    '55' => 'Ordinateurs & Electronique grand public ',
    '68' => 'Matériels et composants électroniques, électriques, informatique professionnelle',
    '37' => 'Matériaux de construction et extraction d\'autres matériaux (hors ènergie)',
    '40' => 'Aéronautique, défense',
    '41' => 'Agroalimentaire, agriculture',
    '42' => 'Automobiles, équipementiers',
    '43' => 'Chimie (fine et lourde), plastique',
    '44' => 'Construction mécanique, métallurgie, sidérurgie, machines-outils',
    '45' => 'Energie ',
    '47' => 'Industrie de l'emballage et fabrication d'autres matériaux',
    '51' => 'Autres activités des industries',
    '56' => 'R&D, pôles de compétitivité',
    '64' => 'Santé, pharmacie, biotech',
    '49' => 'Presse, édition, imprimerie',
    '52' => 'Groupes de médias',
    '53' => 'Culture & Loisirs',
    '81' => 'Portails, pure players Internet',
    '57' => 'Télévision, radio, cinéma',
    '63' => 'Régies publicitaires, affichage',
    '58' => 'Associations, fédérations, syndicats',
    '59' => 'Fondations',
    '50' => 'Restauration collective',
    '60' => 'Enseignement, recherche, formation professionnelle',
    '61' => 'Etablissements médicaux, centre de soins',
    '62' => 'Intérim',
    '65' => 'Services à la personne, action sociale',
    '66' => 'Tourisme, hôtellerie',
    '67' => 'Autres services aux entreprises ou aux collectivités',
    '69' => 'Services environnementaux, facility management',
    '78' => 'Relation Client',
    '19' => 'Support, maintenance et logistique',
    '36' => 'Messagerie, courrier ',
    '70' => 'Transports aériens ',
    '71' => 'Transports ferroviaires et urbains (trains, bus & cars, métro, taxis)',
    '72' => 'Transports maritimes et fluviaux',
    '73' => 'Transports routiers (camions)',
    '76' => 'Infrastructures de transport'
};

/** Map nomination fields with accounts **/
public static void mapFieldsForAccounts(List<Account> accounts){
    if(accounts.size() > 0){
        for(Account anAccount : accounts){

            // Secteur id
            if(anAccount.CNT__TECH_Secteur_ID_Nomination__c != NULL){
                String secteurId = String.valueOf(anAccount.CNT__TECH_Secteur_ID_Nomination__c);

                if(accountSecteurActiviteMap.containsKey(secteurId)){
                    anAccount.CNT__Secteur_d_activit__c = accountSecteurActiviteMap.get(secteurId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
    enter code here

Comment: I do not get any error running your first snippet. Something is missing from your MVR here.

Comment: What's the difference between the first example and the second example? They appear identical and should work just fine as written.

Comment: I tested the map with just that line in the developer console and it works and if I copy/paste mw map from the console to the apex class (salesforce inline), it doesn't work. It's the first time I can see that..

Comment: It sounds like the issue is the Apex class then, and is likely outside the map code you've provided. Are you positive you're not missing a quote somewhere?

Comment: does one of the values in your map include the `'` character within the text? Such as this contrived example? `'Equipement de la m'aison, electroménager'` If so, it needs to be escaped like `'Equipement de la m\'aison, electroménager'`.

Comment: What editor do you use? Is it the developer console? In there I can't recreate an issue with either accent on an e, at least not within a String. The error however sounds more like a variable name of yours starts with a non-ASCII-character.

Comment: I use sublime text and I past my code in the Salesforce inline edit code (not the developer console).
I updated my first post with all my code to help to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with special characters but is caused by unescaped single quotes.
Change the following lines. Note that there are two changes on '47'

FROM:

```
'26' => 'Conseil juridique, cabinets d'avocats', 
'47' => 'Industrie de l'emballage et fabrication d'autres matériaux',
```

TO:

```
'26' => 'Conseil juridique, cabinets d\'avocats',
'47' => 'Industrie de l\'emballage et fabrication d\'autres matériaux',
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the error but why I get an error message for the index 17 but not 26 and 47?

Comment: When I cut-and-paste the long map declaration in your sample I get the error on the '68' line, which is the first line after a missed single quote that contains a letter with an  accent.  Because of the missed quote, the compiler thinks it is an indentifier.  And I believe identifiers in apex must follow this rule. `Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number of ASCII letters (a-z or A-Z), digits (0 - 9), '$', '_'."`  So, the compiler thinks that lines has an invalid identifier.  Look at the color coding in map above.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Clearly, apex strings themselves handle accents and more complete character sets than just ASCII